# Multiple joins in Codeigniter (Active Records)

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to retrieve results from my database with details spanning across tables 'places', 'category' and 'reviews', then sort by number of reviews. When I add the 2nd join, only one row is retrieved.

```
$this->db->select('places.*, category.*')
            ->from('places')
            ->join('category', 'places.category_id = category.category_id')
            ->join('places_reviews', 'places_reviews.place_id = places.id')
            ->where('places.category_id', $category_id)
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);
```

I did not add in the `IFNULL(COUNT(places_reviews('review_id')) AS 'num_reviews', 0)` into the select() function to make the code cleaner.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check you rows in the DB.  The JOIN is making the query only return 1 row, because that's the only row that matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is a `LEFT JOIN`, try:

```
->join('places_reviews', 'places_reviews.place_id = places.id', 'left')
```